Error Encountered During Nest.js Application Initialization with npm Package Manager
I'm encountering an error while trying to initialize a new Nest.js application using the npm package manager. After running the nest new BLUE command and selecting npm as the package manager, the application scaffolding process begins, but it fails during the package installation phase with the following error:Failed to execute command: npm install --silent
've attempted to troubleshoot the issue by retrying the installation manually with 'npm install' in the project directory, but the error persists. This issue is hindering the creation of new Nest.js applications, and I need assistance in resolving it.
Any insights or guidance on how to address this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you
I attempted to initialize a new Nest.js application named "BLUE" using the npm package manager. I expected the application scaffolding process to complete successfully, including the installation of necessary dependencies. However, during the installation phase, the process failed with an error message indicating that the npm install command could not be executed. Despite retrying the installation manually and following troubleshooting steps, the issue persisted, preventing the successful creation of the application.

Please share the rest of the error message or anything else that could be of use to troubleshoot this.
